# Scheduling a job in Jenkins between hours

Tags: jenkins, scheduling

I am fairly new to deploying builds on jenkins so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I need to schedule a build to run every 30 minutes between the hours of 6am and 11pm every day of the week. I see a lot about scheduling builds every hour etc but cant find any resources where its every 30 minutes and between a certain time frame. I have come up with the following syntax for the period build and just wondering if anyone could help with the following:

1. H/30 6-23  * * * - if someone could confirm this is correct (if not help me with the correct syntax)
2. Explain a small bit more what the 3 extra * are about and provide any links to articles/information sites where I could learn a bit more.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your cron is okay. You can learn about the crons below.

Build every hour:
H * * * *

Build every 20 minutes:
H/20 * * * *

Build every 20 minutes 2am to 11pm:
H/20 5-23 * * *

Build every 20 minutes, work time/days (8am-6pm, MON-FRI) only:
H/20 8-18 * * 1-5

Build every hour MON-WED and FRI only:
H * * * 1-3,5

Build every hour, weekends in April and December:
H * * 4,12 *

Build at 8.30am on July 4:
30 8 4 7 *

Jenkins schedule format
Jenkins schedule format is nothing but a cron schedule expression. It contains 5 fields

```
 ┌───────────── minute (0 - 59)
 │ ┌───────────── hour (0 - 23)
 │ │ ┌───────────── day of month (1 - 31)
 │ │ │ ┌───────────── month (1 - 12)
 │ │ │ │ ┌───────────── day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday to Saturday;
 │ │ │ │ │                                       7 is also Sunday on some systems)
 │ │ │ │ │
 │ │ │ │ │
 * * * * *  schedule command to execute
```